# $_GET method into cssfile.php

Tags: php, css, get

I have cssfile.php and am using this code ($st_id =$_GET['staff_id']; $tit = "SELECT * FROM staff where te_id=".$_GET['staff_id']."";) to get value from url and validate with my sql statement but the $_GET method dosen't work in my case ..
help me guys

Comment: Are the parentheses (`()`) around your code part of the code? What does "doesn't work" mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as

```
    $st_id =$_GET['staff_id']; 
$tit = "SELECT * FROM staff where te_id='$st_id'";
```

and then your code work properly :)

Comment: my problem is I cant use $_GET into a css file

Comment: If you use php file and css code then you can use above code between php opening and closing tags: `<?php  //your code; ?>`